# Do rules of grammar apply to unconventional language usage?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I came to "English Language & Usage" in hopes of clarifying a common "Me" or "I" question, and found significant consensus as long as convention is followed: "Me and my wife went to the movies" is incorrect grammar. However, the consensus also seems to be that "I and my wife went to the movies" is incorrect usage because the convention is to "put yourself last because it is polite". So "I and my wife went to the movies" is correct, but don't ever use it!

Which prompted my question: Do rules of grammar apply to unconventional language usage? I understand that it is a simple question for a nuanced subject, but it seems in this example you're left with "Yes, the rules of grammar apply as long as you follow this other thing which is not a rule"!

Comment: Grammatical "rules" aren't like "laws of nature". Effectively, they're either *conventions* (people copying what other people say), or *formalised explanations* (of what people say). So in many cases the very reason why you might describe a usage as "unconventional" is precisely *because* it doesn't follow the rules of grammar. And I and people like me wouldn't say *I and my wife went to the movies* is "incorrect" - it's just "non-idiomatic" for most people.

Comment: You need to ask yourself what your understanding of 'rules of grammar' is and whether it is realistic. Quirk and Svartvik suggest a 5-point gradience for acceptability of constructions (this has been covered here before). They deal with the reality that some people (well educated anglophones) will accept as correct a construction that others won't. So there is no binding agreement on what the 'rules of grammar' actually are; how can one pronounce on 'whether they apply to unconventional language usage'?

Comment: Define "unconventional".

Comment: @Ricky Language is weird. Who is the authority that says what is correct or incorrect? Even supposing there were an authority (like some universally recognized language institute), which of US vs UK rules would be 'the' rules? All these rules are just discovered patterns from what people say, not instructions in an automaton. This doesn't mean anything goes; there certainly are rules, but there are different varieties, meaning some different rules for the same thing. Your school teacher/copy editor recommend 'My wife and I', but informally 'My wife and me' or 'Me and my wife' are usually used.

Comment: Your question seems to assume that "incorrect grammar", "incorrect usage" and "unconventional language usage" are synonymous. Those are three different things, and the last one is an oxymoron. I also don't understand how you get from "the consensus also seems to be that 'I and my wife went to the movies' is **incorrect** usage" to "So 'I and my wife went to the movies' is **correct**".

Comment: Okay, I've voted to close the question on the grounds that answers would be primarily opinion-based, that its unclear what you're asking, and that the question is too broad to admit an answer of appropriate length. I think it might be a valuable question to have answered here or on the meta site, but as it stands the question isn't susceptible to a good answer, and you don't seem willing to address the problems.

Comment: @JEL New to StackExchange and not sure what voting to close the question entails, but for what it's worth the question has not been answered -- and to be fair perhaps it couldn't be -- but the answers, comments and exchanges have been very enlightening.

Comment: @rwhtx, voting to close simply means the question isn't perceived (by those so voting) as fitting the rules of engagement given by, for example, the help tour. Other than that, voting to close has no significance I know of. If closed, no new answers can be made for the question. I think your question is good, but can't give you a good answer as it stands because of the problems I mentioned. I don't think you've gotten a good answer, but if you're satisfied, my opinion is probably irrelevant.

Comment: @JEL One more attempt at clarification. I don’t consider the three concepts you mention to be synonymous, and as stated “I and my wife ...” is incorrect because of convention (or etiquette) but grammatically correct. 
It seems “Hot Licks” had the most valid issue with the question ... define “unconventional”. Rather than define, let me just say I chose the word in response the references on this forum to the “convention” that one does not “put himself first” in a list of people. Hence “I and my wife” is unconventional language. 
Other clarification below in comments on answers.

Comment: Yes, I upticked @HotLicks' comment because it seemed to me it struck at the heart of the problem. Other difficulties are with 'moving-target' definitions. I understand your comments on the question and answers. I composed a long-winded and finally unsatisfactory 'answer', but bogged down in backgrounding: one example is the simple observation that language *is* entirely conventional. Unconventional language isn't incorrect so much as it is uncommunicative. Therefore, the convention violated by putting 'I' first is social rather than linguistic; it's a matter of politeness, not grammar.

Comment: It seems to me your question is really a tautology:  "Unconventional language" is language which does not adhere to the conventions for the language.  Conventions have different degrees of severity, but that simply means that a particular utterance can be more or less conventional, and one's cutoff for what's "acceptable" can be more or less accepting of "violations" of the conventions.  Different people have different criteria for "acceptable", and even an individual person will have different criteria for formal vs informal speech.

Comment: Again, very enlightening. Unfortunately my takeaway is that in some cases this forum may not allow themselves to consider the actual question, focusing rather on whether the question itself is adequately constructed.  i.e. not seeing the clumsily written forest for the linguistically or logically precise trees. I simply thought it was curious that in this one example to "speak correctly" the Rules of Grammar cannot be followed if the social convention of not putting "I" first is violated. Two rule books, as it were. And I asked a question about that.

Comment: The site does aim to generate well-formed questions and answers, with minimal success in that aim. However, I still fail to see the basis of your question: "My wife and I" (subject) follows both rule books, does it not?

Comment: "My wife and I ..." follows both rule books.  /  What if I didn’t want to follow the convention of “not putting myself first”? Be unconventional?   /   “Me and my wife went to the movies.” I think most would agree that this is grammatically incorrect.   /   “I and my wife went to the movies.” While grammatically correct I think most, including all high school English teachers, would consider this “incorrect”.   /   Do the generally accepted “Rules of Grammar” apply in this instance?      /   BTW, I do appreciate the aim, and I think the site does a very good job in accomplishing it.

Comment: You keep talking around in circles.  The "generally accepted rules" for English include both the "strict" grammar rules and the what you call the social conventions.  You can choose to follow or violate any of these rules you want.  If you do, you may cause some people to think less highly of you,  or you may instead appear to be "badder" to your social circle.  It's up to you.

Comment: (Personally, I strictly adhere to *all* of the rules, including the one about never using a preposition to end a sentence with.)

Comment: I don't know if it's appropriate to respond to a question being put on hold, but I don't think there would be much gained by rewording the question and suggest closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linguists study grammars in order to describe them. As such, they ask questions like 'How do English speakers order nouns and pronouns that collectively constitute the subject of a sentence?' (e.g. *my wife and I* denotes the subject of your example sentence) and 'Under what conditions might English speakers order them differently?'. As such, the way that speakers use a language determines its grammar.

We might define language *A* as the set of words and permutative rules that enable a set of people to comprehend one another when they use that set of words and rules to communicate.

Therefore, unconventional use isn't ungrammatical use, so long as speakers of the language can comprehend it.

Questions on the appropriateness of phrases such as 'I and my wife' are, at bottom, stylistic questions.

Comment: First, some background: 1) new to this forum, 2) not a linguist, and 3) while a native english speaker ... I am from Texas. My interest was in what I assume are generally accepted "Rules of Grammar" and commonly accepted (or prescribed) usage. And in that context, I must admit the answer and the comments do not provide much clarity. But in retrospect, perhaps the subject is too nuanced for a simple question.

Comment: `herefore, unconventional use isn't ungrammatical use` That's not right, lots of ungrammatical language can still be understood because there's sufficient redundancy that we can identify the errors.

Comment: @rwhtx The problem is that there is no such thing as generally accepted rules of grammar: different people (many claiming to be authorities, none without overstating their own status) will give you different rules. In “commonly accepted usage” (by which I mean what people actually say and understand without batting an eyelid), both _me and my wife_ and _I and my wife_ and _my wife and me_ are in fact perfectly standard and conventional.

Comment: Of course there are generally accepted rules of grammar. "My dog are the goodest" is most certainly bad grammar (and spelling) -- even if everybody doesn’t agree on what good grammar is. But that is not the point. What is interesting is the concept of a set of rules applying only to a defined construct which is itself a set of rules, and if the occurrence is outside that construct the rules do not apply, i.e. grammar is the set of rules on how to speak or write if you speak or write according to the rules. It seems odd, and brings into question the legitimacy of the rules in the first place.

Comment: @rhtwx Yeah, I don't think the comprehensible=grammatical answer works for particular sentences. But note that there would be a comprehension problem if you were to present that sentence more abstractly: if you had written *x are the goodest*, I would have interpreted it to presuppose the existence of more than one x. In regard to *the goodest*, why we use *best* instead of *goodest* is a question about the English lexicon and not so much a question about English grammar.

Answer (score -4):

There's no such thing as "conventional" English.

There's standard English, and also formal English and informal English. There are also dialects. The rest is just idiocy.

**1. My wife and I went to the movies last night.**

This is standard English.

**2. Me and my wife went to the movies the other night.**

This is totally wrong but perfectly acceptable.

**3. A friend called my wife and I the other night.**

Idiocy. Wait, it gets worse:

**4. I reserved seats for my wife and I.**

Thing is there used to be, and still is, a rather large group of people (an entire class in fact) known as the Philistines. (Well, they used to be known as the Philistines: the word is all but forgotten today because Philistines are easily offended while constituting a significant portion of the electorate).

They wish to come off as "educated" ("genteel") without actually learning anything. They believe they can get away with a few adjustment to their speech and manners. Someone explained to them at some point that "me" was wrong and "I" was right. They pounced on it. To this day they're convinced that so long as they say "I" where their instincts urge them to say "me," they'll come off as "educated" ("genteel") and will be able to condescend to anyone who says "me."

The problem with that approach is that sometimes saying "I" instead of me is correct, and sometimes it isn't. Oh, and there are instances when neither "I" nor "me" applies, and one actually needs to use "myself" instead. Don't tell the Philistines, their heads will explode.

Earnest and intelligent discourse on the English case system is all but impossible today, for various reasons.

The rule of thumb is you can arrive at the correct way of saying things by locking the wife up in the closet for a moment.

A friend called I the other night.
I reserved a seat for I the other night.

Both are clearly idiotic. That's because when the action is directed towards you (i.e. when the case is not nominative), you must use "me," and sometimes you must use "myself" (as in "for my wife and myself").

Another way to look at it is to remember that you should use "me" where you would use "her" and "him," and "I" where you would "she" and "he." (Try saying "A friend called my wife and she the other night." Stupid, right? That's exactly how people sound when they say "A friend called my wife and I the other night."

A Philistine is a person whose position in the food chain exceeds their cultural and/or spiritual level.

Something like that.

Comment: Can you add an authority clearly defining 'standard English'? Or is this an assumption?

Comment: Can you add an authority clearly defining authority? Goodness.

Comment: *Earnest and intelligent discourse on the English case system is all but impossible today*  Certainly if we're to go by this answer.

Comment: I've added a downvote not because of your refusal to address what you mean by 'standard English' (which has been argued over here before), but because 'This is totally wrong but perfectly acceptable.' is worse than the errors you are calling 'idiocy' etc.

Comment: @Ricky It's true that there's no accepted central authority that governs what is and is not acceptable English, but you make a lot of strong assertions in this answer, and the SE requires that any assertions that aren't self-evident be backed up with some kind of reference or sufficiently demonstrative example - Otherwise, the correctness of your answers will only be apparent to people who know the correct answers already, rather than to people who would actually benefit from some instruction.

Comment: @user867: I'm kind of allergic to relativism. It just annoys me somehow. When someone says that grass is green and the moon is round and is then told that that is merely an opinion, I get this overpowering desire to go to the tropics, lie on the beach all day surrounded by beautiful naked girls, drink champagne, and listen to verismo opera for a while.

Comment: @Ricky Relativism serves a purpose, and this site depends on it as a way of sifting out the correct answers from the "idiocy," as you describe it. If someone says "The answer is X!" and then doesn't actually provide any evidence that X is the answer, then they might as well be talking out of their hat; We have no way to tell if their answer is correct or entirely imaginary. An answer that only *might* be correct is more time consuming and less useful than no answer at all, and so tends to accumulate downvotes.

Comment: “This is totally wrong but completely acceptable” is beyond idiocy. It is sheer and utter lunacy, and every bit as misguidedly Philistine as always using _I_ instead of _me_, in precisely the same way. It's also a bit dubious to say that there is no such thing as conventional English, and then immediately list four common types of conventional English in the following sentence, but that's a minor issue in comparison.